# Azure Databricks API, how to attach a cluster to an uploaded notebook via API

Tags: python, azure, databricks, azure-databricks

I am using python 3.6 to run the following script to upload a local file to Azure databricks notebooks in a specific folder. I have followed the documentation in [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/workspace#--import). With the script below I have been able to upload the notebook. However, I couldn't figure out how I can attach a cluster to this notebook after it is uploaded via the API. I couldn't find it in the documentation. Is it possible altogether? If yes, how?

The python script I am using is as follows:

```
import requests
import os
from os.path import isfile, join
from os import listdir
import base64


dbrks_create_dir_url =  "https://"+os.environ['DBRKS_INSTANCE']+".azuredatabricks.net/api/2.0/workspace/mkdirs"
dbrks_import_rest_url = "https://"+os.environ['DBRKS_INSTANCE']+".azuredatabricks.net/api/2.0/workspace/import"


DBRKS_REQ_HEADERS = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + os.environ['DBRKS_BEARER_TOKEN'],
    'X-Databricks-Azure-Workspace-Resource-Id': '/subscriptions/'+ os.environ['DBRKS_SUBSCRIPTION_ID'] +'/resourceGroups/'+ os.environ['DBRKS_RESOURCE_GROUP'] +'/providers/Microsoft.Databricks/workspaces/' + os.environ['DBRKS_WORKSPACE_NAME'],
    'X-Databricks-Azure-SP-Management-Token': os.environ['DBRKS_MANAGEMENT_TOKEN']}

## This is the address of the notebook to upload.
notebooks = os.environ['DefaultWorkingDirectory'] + "/notebooks/"

    
path = notebooks
onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir(path) if isfile(join(path, f))]
for file in onlyfiles:
  fileLocation = path +"/"+ file 

  data = open(fileLocation, "rb").read()
  encoded = base64.b64encode(data)
  files = {"content": (fileLocation,encoded)}

  if ".py" in file:
    fileName = file.split(".")[0]
    fileName = fileName.replace(".py", "")
    print(fileName)
    response = requests.post(dbrks_import_rest_url,headers=DBRKS_REQ_HEADERS, files=files, data={'path': '/Users/myuser/' + fileName, 'language':'PYTHON','format':'SOURCE', 'overwrite': 'true', 'content': encoded})


  if response.status_code == 200:
      print(response.json)
  else:
      raise Exception(response.content)
```

All the OS environment variables are sent from my Azure DevOps pipeline. However, you don't need to execute the script from a pipeline. You can execute it from your local machine as long as you have a service principal with access to a databricks workspace. To run the python script, you can replace those environment variables with your own credentials.

**Explaining the variables in the script:**

- os.environ['DBRKS_INSTANCE']: Name of the databricks instance
- os.environ['DBRKS_BEARER_TOKEN']: the bearer token. You need this to authenticate your service principal or your user to databricks. Later I have explained how you can get it.
- os.environ['DBRKS_MANAGEMENT_TOKEN']: If the service principle you are using is not added as databricks workspace users or admins, you need this token. Later I have explained how you can get it.
- os.environ['DBRKS_SUBSCRIPTION_ID']: The Azure subscription Id where databricks workspace is.
- os.environ['DBRKS_RESOURCE_GROUP']: Name of the Azure resource group of the databricks workspace.
- os.environ['DBRKS_WORKSPACE_NAME']: Name of the Azure databricks workspace.
- os.environ["DBRKS_CLUSTER_ID"]: The cluster Id which will execute the job in databricks.
- os.environ['DefaultWorkingDirectory']: simply replace it with the address on your local machine for a sample notebook file. A notebook file is just a file with .py extension. You can put a comment in this file or just print("Hello World!").

One final point to make the above script run: To get the above two variables for DBRKS_BEARER_TOKEN and DBRKS_MANAGEMENT_TOKEN, you can run the following script and manually replace os.environ['DBRKS_BEARER_TOKEN'] and os.environ['DBRKS_MANAGEMENT_TOKEN'] with the printed values after script execution:

```
import requests
import json
import os


TOKEN_BASE_URL = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/' + os.environ['SVCDirectoryID'] + '/oauth2/token'
TOKEN_REQ_HEADERS = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
TOKEN_REQ_BODY = {
       'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
       'client_id': os.environ['SVCApplicationID'],
       'client_secret': os.environ['SVCSecretKey']}



def dbrks_management_token():
        TOKEN_REQ_BODY['resource'] = 'https://management.core.windows.net/'
        response = requests.get(TOKEN_BASE_URL, headers=TOKEN_REQ_HEADERS, data=TOKEN_REQ_BODY)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            print(response.status_code)
        else:
            raise Exception(response.text)
        return response.json()['access_token']


def dbrks_bearer_token():
        TOKEN_REQ_BODY['resource'] = '2ff814a6-3304-4ab8-85cb-cd0e6f879c1d'
        response = requests.get(TOKEN_BASE_URL, headers=TOKEN_REQ_HEADERS, data=TOKEN_REQ_BODY)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            print(response.status_code)
        else:
            raise Exception(response.text)
        return response.json()['access_token']

DBRKS_BEARER_TOKEN = dbrks_bearer_token()
DBRKS_MANAGEMENT_TOKEN = dbrks_management_token()

os.environ['DBRKS_BEARER_TOKEN'] = DBRKS_BEARER_TOKEN 
os.environ['DBRKS_MANAGEMENT_TOKEN'] = DBRKS_MANAGEMENT_TOKEN 

print("DBRKS_BEARER_TOKEN",os.environ['DBRKS_BEARER_TOKEN'])
print("DBRKS_MANAGEMENT_TOKEN",os.environ['DBRKS_MANAGEMENT_TOKEN'])
```

- SVCDirectoryID is Azure Active Directory (AAD) service principal tenant Id
- SVCApplicationID is the value of AAD service principal client Id.
- SVCSecretKey is AAD service principal secret key.

Thank you for your valuable input.

Comment: what do you mean by attaching? Are you looking for execution of that notebook as a job?

Comment: @AlexOtt yes, exactly. I am looking for a way to execute the notebook after being uploaded. So attaching a cluster is important.

Comment: @AlexOtt is it altogether possible to execute a notebook via the API? My workaround is to use a job as a proxy between notebook and cluster. But I was wondering if API allows us do it more simply.

Comment: There is an old API (1.2) to execute individual commands, but it will be even more complicated… Jobs is the simplest way to execute notebooks

Comment: Are you trying to execute tests in the notebook?

Comment: Exactly. I am thinking to put the unittests inside a notebook, upload it, execute it and if the tests are successful, continue with installing the package on the cluster.

Comment: Use Nutter for that, here is the full demo: https://github.com/alexott/databricks-nutter-repos-demo, and use Repos instead of uploading notebooks

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [User Alex Ott - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18627/alex-ott) . Posting your suggestions as answer to help other community members.

You can use [Nutter framework](https://github.com/alexott/databricks-nutter-repos-demo) for Databricks notebooks, use Repos instead of uploading notebooks.

Your Databricks workspace needs to have Repos functionality enabled. If it's enabled, you should see the "**Repos**" icon in the navigation panel:

- Fork repository into your environment - Github, or Azure DevOps (follow Databricks documentation on using it)
- In the **Repos**, click "**Create Repo**" and link it to the Git repository that you've forked

[image]

References: [GitHub - microsoft/nutter: Testing framework for Databricks notebooks](https://github.com/microsoft/nutter) and [GitHub - alexott/databricks-nutter-repos-demo: Demo of using the Nutter for testing of Databricks notebooks in the CI/CD pipeline](https://github.com/alexott/databricks-nutter-repos-demo)